# Factory method problem

Tags: php, oop, factory-pattern

Why does `User::factory()` create an object, but `User::factory()->get()` not? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
class User {

    public $name;
    public $email;

    public static function factory()
    {
        return new User();
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $this->name = 'Foo Bar';
        $this->email = 'foo.bar@baz.com';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User::factory()` creates an object because it returns an object made by an constructor. `User::factory()->get()` creates an object and calls the get method, but the get method do not return the object, so it gets destructed afterwards. If you want your get method to return the object, just use `return $this;` at the end of the method. 
Otherwise assign the returned object to variable and then call get:

```
$user = User::factory();
$user->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your get *return $this;*.

Answer (score 1):

The get method is not returning anything. You can add:

```
   return $this;
```

as the last line of the get method if you want it to return an object.